# Get media information being casted by SoundCloud or Spotify on android tv in iOS

Tags: ios, google-cast, android-tv, google-cast-sdk

I want to get the information of what is being casted on android tv by any application e.g SoundCloud, Spotify or Youtube. Also I want to add controls to change volume, previous/next, play/pause for the casting. Similar thing is done by **Google Home**.
I've tried using *GoogleCast* but If I connect my app SoundCloud stops casting. If I don't connect to device then `currentSession` and `currentCastSession` are nil.
Is this possible to do If yes Can please anyone point me in the right direction
I've added a sample screenshot of **Google Home**[image: It shows current playing item and controls]